# Why are programmatically created (bottom) toolbar button titles not displaying?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

In Swift 3, I've programmatically created a (bottom) toolbar with custom buttons separated by a flexible spacer to separate the custom buttons, pushing one ("Previous") to the left edge and the other ("Next") to the right edge of the view. But I have not been able to get the button titles ("Previous" and "Next") to display. Please advise me. Thanks. Here is my code:

First, the class declaration and a few variables:

```
class TextsController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

let textWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
var toolbar:UIToolbar?
```

Next, in the viewDidLoad:

```
    view = textWebView

    // Create (bottom) toolbar:
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height-44, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 44)
    toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: frame)
    toolbar?.sizeToFit()
    toolbar?.isHidden = true
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar!)
    self.toolbar?.isTranslucent = false // Required for setting tintColor & barTintColor below

    toolbar?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) //purple for toolbar items
    toolbar?.barTintColor = UIColor.white //white for toolbar color

    let triangleLeftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "triangleLeft_15x20"), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(showPrevious))
    let flexibleSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.flexibleSpace , target: self, action: nil)
    let triangleRightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "triangleRight_15x20"), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(showNext))

    triangleLeftButton.title = "Previous"
    triangleRightButton.title = "Next"

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(triangleLeftButton)
    items.append(flexibleSpacer)
    items.append(triangleRightButton)
    toolbar?.items = items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this.

I eliminated the two statements attempting to assign a title to each button (I do wonder why Xcode did not flag that, allowing me to assign a title to each initially, though neither title would display).

I rewrote (compare the code below with the code in the question) the UIBarButtonItems as follows to now include two text items:

```
    // Create toolbar items (buttons and texts)
    let triangleLeftButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "triangleLeft_15x20"), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(showPrevious))
    let triangleLeftText = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Previous", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    let flexibleSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.flexibleSpace , target: self, action: nil)
    let triangleRightText = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    let triangleRightButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "triangleRight_15x20"), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(showNext))
```

Then I appended everything, including the two new text items, to the array:

```
    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(triangleLeftButton)
    items.append(triangleLeftText)
    items.append(flexibleSpacer)
    items.append(triangleRightText)
    items.append(triangleRightButton)
    toolbar?.items = items
```

This effectively places "Previous" adjacent to the left-pointing button and "Next" adjacent to the right-pointing button, with the flexible spacer affording a nice wide gap between.

Answer (score 0):

A custom view or image bar button item has no title. A bar button item is *either* a title *or* a custom view *or* an image. If you want some words to appear in a custom view or image bar button item, make those words part of the custom view or image.

Comment: In imagining an image with a title underneath it, you may be confusing a UIBarButtonItem with a UITabBarItem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I intend to make the text (what I called "title") change dynamically, depending on what text is currently displayed in the WKWebView. For example, if I am currently on page 2, I want the triangleLeft button to display "1" and the triangleRight button to display "3"  (I merely used "Previous" and "Next" as interim placeholders for what I intend to address later). I'll later add functionality to make those buttons summon page 1 or page 3 to the WKWebView. So making the desired words part of the custom image does not help.

Comment: Go ahead and "intend" that. But that is not what a UIBarButtonItem _is_. Reality supervenes.